# Directory does and doesn't exist

Tags: android

I am trying to write a file to the SD card on my android phone, but it seems to be having issues with the directory.  It exists but doesnt exist.  By this I mean when I go to the file browser on the android phone, and look for the GPStracker folder I cannot find it.  Yet in the program it seems to acknowledge that this directory exists when it checks the `dir.exists()` if condition below.  Then when it gets to the `canWrite()` function it always returns false.  I have no idea what is wrong at this point, anyone have any debugging ideas?  Thanks.

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

^ These both return true now, got that issue fixed.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tinywebteam.gpstracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.tinywebteam.gpstracker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code:

```
try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard + "/GPStracker/data");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs())
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Couldn't make directory.");
                if (!dir.isDirectory())
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Couldn't verify directory.");
            }
            File fileOut = new File(dir, "GPSTracker_" + ts + ".csv");
            if (fileOut.canWrite()) {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
                out.write(fileStr.getBytes());
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File written successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not write to file");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your code does not say that it exists.. It attempts to make the directory if it does not exist. It should at this point report a fail infact to make the directory.

Comment: Errrr, `if (!dir.exists())` doesn't this say if the directory doesn't exist, create it?  Shouldn't it exist at this point if it skips this block of code?  At this point it always skips this block of code as condition evaluates to false.  It then goes straight to the fileOut line.

Comment: Okay, so its something to do with your file. It is unable to write the file, maybe due to an invalid name?> what is `ts`?

Comment: Try `new File(sdCard, "test.csv");` Rule out that its a directory/naming problem

Comment: @Doomsknight ts is a timestamp long.  I just attempted with no directories, and its still failing the `canWrite()` condition.  Is it possible the SD card is in the wrong format of some sort?

Comment: You could remove the ` if (fileOut.canWrite()) {`.  Try without that if statement, and just write to file. See if it saves. I never use canWrite